# Syntax for return after function

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim

I try to reproduce this lines of code from gensim

```
import gensim
def coherence_values_computation(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, start=2, step=3):
   coherence_values = []
   model_list = []
   for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
      model = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(
         mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word
      )
      model_list.append(model)
   coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(
      model=model, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v'
   )
   coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())
return model_list, coherence_values
```

However in the return function I receive this error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-10-65490721eef3>", line 13
>     return model_list, coherence_values)
>     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Any idea with this happens?

Comment: The code in the question does not produce that error. Please edit it and provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: You might need to check your ( ) - if they balance. Missing a ) makes for weird error messages as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` should be inside the function. Indentation should be:

```
def coherence_values_computation(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, start=2, step=3):
   coherence_values = []
   model_list = []
   for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
      model = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(
         mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word
      )
      model_list.append(model)
   coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(
      model=model, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v'
   )
   coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())
   return model_list, coherence_values
```